# Rails 3.2: Why does my master branch see the capistrano-stats gem from my rails4 upgrade branch and can I deploy master?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, capistrano

I've been working in a `rails4` branch for a while now, upgrading the app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2. In the meantime, I realized that some things that had previously been merged into `master` were never deployed, so I switched back to `master` and ran `cap production deploy`.

All of a sudden, I got this prompt from capistrano that I'd never seen before:

```
MBA:myapp david$ cpd
        Would you like to enable statistics?  Here is an example message we would
        send:

      1|2015-01-21T10:59:17-05:00|1.9.3|x86_64-darwin14.0.0|3.3.5|c52f7ecf
```

As mentioned above, I never received this prompt when deploying previously.  Here is my `Gemfile.lock` for capistrano on `master`:

```
capistrano (3.2.1)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
```

...and on `rails4`:

```
 capistrano (3.3.5)
      capistrano-stats (~> 1.1.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-stats (1.1.1)
```

I notice right away that `capistrano-stats` exists in the `Gemfile.lock` for the `rails4` branch but not in `master`. Yet I'm still getting the statistics prompt when deploying `master`, even if I run `bundle install` on the `master` branch before deploying.

Can someone explain how this is working with Git, and what the consequences of deploying `master` would be at this point since it seems to be seeing things (gems) from the `rails4` branch even though I haven't merged it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying `master`, but you have checked out the `rails4` branch in local git, you are still deploying using your local config (from the `rails4` branch).

This is due to the fact, that capistrano does not checkout the branch you want to deploy locally, only on the server you are deploying to and config is loaded before this is done.

**UPDATE**

We found out, that running with and without `bundle exec` runs different versions of capistrano (with `bundle exec` being the correct one).

If you have more versions of capistrano, it can happen that the non-local one will be selected, but the with highest version will.

To solve that, you can generate a binstub for your capistrano with `bundle binstub cap`; afterwards you will see that an executable has been added (as `./bin/cap`) and if you add `./bin` to your `PATH`, you will be able to run without `bundle exec` again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. The `rails4` branch exists but I checked out `master` before doing the deploy. The order from within `rails4` was `git checkout master` -> `bundle install` -> `cap production deploy`

Comment: Correction to my last comment: I do understand what you mean about capistrano checking out the branch to be deployed on the server rather than locally. But I still don't understand why I'm getting the prompt from that gem in my master branch when it only seems to exist in the `rails4` branch.

Comment: Does this happen if you run `spring stop` and then capistrano again?

Comment: can you please post output of `cap -v`? another option: what happens if you run your deployment with `bundle exec cap ...`?

Comment: when I run `cap -v` from master branch I get `Capistrano Version: 3.3.5 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)`. 3.3.5 is the version that I upgraded to on the `rails4` branch. However....when I prefix the deploy command with `bundle exec` it looks like everything works normally like before!